# What do I call a person who is well qualified but has failed in his life?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am writing a story, and I need a single word or phrase as a topic for

> A person who has failed to achieve success despite his high educational attainment.

Here is an example:

> A person has Masters and Ph.D. degrees, but is a poor shopkeeper. He cannot even arrange the basic facilities of life for himself and his family.

The word could be a noun or an adjective.

Comment: You can call them any number of things. If you don't know what to call them given all the additional details and context that you have, we certainly don't know what to call them when said details and context are withheld from us.

Comment: As an aside, it's quite an attitude to regard being a shopkeeper as "failing at life". Especially if someone has actual "certain reasons" to be a shopkeeper. In my ideal world, everyone has a PhD. In your ideal world, there aren't even shopkeepers. Sucks.

Comment: @RegDwigнt To be fair, the text says 'a poor shopkeeper', which I took to mean someone who had failed to make a go of shopkeeping, but it is ambiguous. Perhaps the OP could sharpen up the question?

Comment: I mentioned poor alongside shopkeeper.A person who is running a shop of low level and cannot even arrange to get the basic facilities for himself and his family despite having a well qualified PHD degree.Now is that information enough?

Comment: @RegDwigHt I make the educated guess that 'poor shopkeeper' is used within a background of Indian English to mean impoverished small trader, which is apparently a failure (according to OP) for somebody with the highest qualifications. However native speakers of English reading 'poor shopkeeper' might think (as I first did, though I am Indian) that the hypothetical person failed at some business venture. OP wants a single word for **a person who is a material or financial failure despite the highest educational qualifications.** I am only trying to explain the context of 'poor shopkeeper' here.

Comment: @EnglishStudent Yes! you absolutely got me right

Comment: So not being able to keep a shop going is his failure but not being able to find a way to earn a return on his degree "because of lack of opportunity for that specific expertise" is the market's failure? That seems inconsistent. Why blame him for one but not the other? Why blame the market for one but not the other?

Comment: @DanBron leave the blaming part because it is for a story. I just need the term for that specific case. A person who has failed to achieve success despite his high educational attainment.

Comment: @user237875 Ok, fair enough. I've edited your post to reflect all this additional information you've kindly provided in the comments. Use the updated question as a guide for your next question. The more detail you provide up front, in the actual question and not comments, and the more clearly you present it (including standard orthography, spacing, spelling, punctuation, formatting and so on), the faster and better answers you'll get.

Comment: @Dan Bron only the hypothetical person's back story can reveal exactly 'why' he is struggling for a living running a small shop in spite of having a PhD -- depending on whether he was incompetent, unfortunate or recalcitrant! Certainly the market cannot be 'blamed' unless there is a genuine shortage of opportunities.

Comment: Can you give a sentence with a slot for this word? Or do you just want to say "This person is a X"/"This person is Y"?

Comment: @user237875 ?? That's not a sentence with a slot. Or is 'this' where you want the word to go? It would help us a lot if you could give a sentence where you expected term would fi.

Comment: @Mitch I think OP simply wants a term that describes such a person. As in, "Mr.A has a Ph.D but is struggling for a living as a small shopkeeper. He is a ________________" This term might be the topic of the story and possibly also its title.

Comment: OP, if you are bold enough, you might simply consider the word 'failure' as in "The Failure - a story about a man who is highly educated, but a failure"-- it would be a provocative title and the reader would be interested to read it and find out **why?** -- you can explore many social and psychological issues and even bring out how this person is ***not*** a failure in a spiritual sense, etc. I SAY BOLD because some people don't like to use negative titles like 'failure.'

Answer (score 5):

This person is an

***overeducated underachiever***

> [overeducated](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overeducated): Having been educated to a higher academic level than is necessary. *(Oxford Living Dictionaries)*
>
> [underachiever](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/underachiever): someone who is less successful than they should be at school or at work *(Cambridge)*

Or you could say this person

> is highly educated, but short on common sense.

Or that he

> has his head in the clouds

or he

> is too smart for his own good.

*Loser, failure, flop, useless* could be used in place of *underachiever*, but they're more hurtful words.

(There might also be a good word in Yiddish for this.)

Comment: **Just** the word that occured to me; Upvote! Looking at OP's descriprion and your definition (and this is why I hesitated to suggest that word before) this person is an **overachiever** at studies ***and an underachiever*** at work! Now OP can ask: I am writing a story: what is a single word or phrase for somebody who is an overachiever at one thing **and** an underachiever at another?

Comment: Note 2: I would agree with Reg DwigHt and disagree with OP that just because this fictional person has not achieved the material or financial success commensurate with his high educational qualifications, he cannot be called a 'failure in life' **unless he feels so himself.** I know many persons who are highly successful educationally, materially and financially ***yet*** consider themselves a failure in life!